# calculating X, Y, Z random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose X, Y, and Z are random variables that each take the value 0 or 1. If P(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)=1/3 and P(X=0,Y=1,Z=1)=1/4, what is the value of P(X=0,Y=1)?

I am trying to calculate this but I am really struggling to figure out how exactly. My initial thought was to try and do 1/3 - 1/4 but this is just a gut intuition. Not sure really how to tackle this problem.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Why would it be minus?

Comment: I am not sure. I was just trying the first thing that came to mind. But I do not think this is the right method of going about it. This is what I need help with.

Comment: Can you tell if the _event_ $(X=0, Y=1)$ occurred when you are told that the event $(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)$ has occurred? How about when you are told that the event $(X=0,Y=1,Z=1)$ has occurred? If your answer is No in either case, what would you say are the values of $X$ and $Y$ in each case?

Comment: @userunknown `I was just trying the first thing that came to mind.`  Would it have come to mind if the numerical values of the probabilities had been interchanged?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Good question. I would say that you can tell that (X=0, Y=1) happened from the given information because if the cases were independent you could say P(X=1)P(Y=1)P(Z=0) or P(X=1)P(Y=1)P(Z=1). But I still do not see how this helps

Comment: In any case, subtracting makes not much sense, because then probabilities could easily become negative, right?

Comment: All right, consider a gazillion trials of the experiment on $33.3\%$ of which the event $(X=0,Y=1,Z=0)$ occurred and on a **different** 25% of which the event $(X=0,Y=1,Z=1)$ occurred. **Be absolutely sure you understand why the two sets of trials MUST be different, and why it is the case that $(X,Y,Z)$ cannot have value $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ on the same trial.**  So on what percentage of the gazillion trials did the event $(X=0,Y=1)$ occur?

Comment: it happened on 58.3% of the trials in this case. Which makes sense. I understand why they are different trials.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your lecture notes for the Law of Total Probability. Using that law would give you:

$P(X=0, Y=1) = P(X=0, Y=1, Z=0) + P(X=0, Y=1, Z=1) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$